# How can I send Drush commands to Pantheon

Tags: drupal, drush, pantheon

I am trying to migrate my drupal 7 siteto drupal 8 site that resides on pantheon. For this purpose I have installed 3 migration modules as described in the docs. I have added my drush aliases in drush directory and I can see all my sites available:

[image]

I am using this drush commands to migrate my data to drupal 8 site on pantheon:

`drush @pantheon.syyamtwo.dev drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only`

But when I execute this I get the following error:

[image]

My drush version is: 8.3.1

Comment: What is the output of `drush @pantheon.syyamtwo.dev status` ? I don't know if it's a typo but your command should be `drush @pantheon.syyamtwo.dev migrate-upgrade --configure-only`

Comment: Actually it's a mistake in the command that you are seeing in the screenshot (Corrected now), but with correct command the error is the same. "The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression.". I am unable to use the '@' keyword.

Comment: Does this happen also with "status" command ? Did you try to enclose the alias with quotes ?

Comment: The status command runs fine, what do you mean by enclosing the quotes?

Comment: I just meant enclosing with quotes like `"@your.alias"` but never mind, it's not that since the status command runs fine

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [terminus](https://pantheon.io/docs/terminus), `terminus drush [site-name.site-env] -- drush_command`.  Where site-name and site-env are your pantheon values.

Here is what that looks like for migration-tools drush commmands on a site name "foo" with an environment "bar":

```
terminus drush foo.bar -- ms
terminus drush foo.bar -- mim --tag=terms
```

Notice the use of `--`, this allows you to pass options to the drush command.